# drawing lines on Android with OpenGL ES 1.0

Tags: android, opengl-es

The following code attempts to draw the frame of the GLSurfaceView and a diagonal line but the result is a big black screen instead. I try to set up orthonogal projection, align the viewport size to the View size, draw the frame lines with glDrawArrays() and the diagonal line with glDrawElements(). I couldn't find the source of the problem.

```
public class MapView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {

private int w, h;

private FloatBuffer frameVertices;

private ByteBuffer diagIndices;

public MapView(Context ctx) { this(ctx, null); }

public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setRenderer(this);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, frameVertices);
    gl.glColor4f(0f, 0f, 1f, 0.5f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, 1, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, diagIndices);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    w = getWidth(); h =  getHeight();
    TRC.debug("w = " + w + ", h = " + h);
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.glDepthRangex(1, -1);    // TODO remove
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthox(0, w, 0, h, 1, -1);

    float[] frame = {
        0, 0,
        w-1, 0,
        w-1, h-1,
        0, h-1 };
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(frame.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    frameVertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    frameVertices.put(frame);
    frameVertices.flip();
    frameVertices.position(0);
    gl.glLineWidthx(10);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    diagIndices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2);
    diagIndices.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    diagIndices.put(new byte[] {0, 2});
    diagIndices.flip();
}

}
```

What can be the matter?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. I used `glOrthox()`, I thought `x` simply means integer value. But that is not exactly, that is treated with a binary point at the middle. `16bit.16bit`. My vertices was out of screen range... My solution was to change `glOrthox()` into `glOrthof()`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `gl.glDepthRangex()` method call, and your near and far clipping planes are switched in `gl.glOrthox()`. Other than that, I don't see anything wrong. Try setting a different clear color with `gl.glClearColor()`, I don't think it'll make much of a difference though.

On second thought, the near clip plane might be better off as 0, try this: `gl.glOrthox(0, w, 0, h, 0, 1);`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking a look at it. I tried different clear color and that has effect. I changed the clipping plane to 0, 1 and didn't notice any difference. The whole view is filled with the clear color (good, at least I know that some part of the GL is working).

Comment: First try changing hardcoding the vertices to random points towards the middle of the screen. If you don't see anything, try using `int error = gl.glGetError(); if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) { Log.e(error); }` at the end of your draw method to see if there's a specific error that OpenGL is throwing. Your error will be an int, you can look up the meaning [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html) and an explanation of the error code [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GL_Error_Codes). Comment with the error here and I'll look into it further.

Comment: glGetError() returned with 0 after every GL call in the onDrawFrame() method. Now what I try is to change the projection from perspective based into orthogonal in downloaded examples sources. The modified example is working although my app doesn't and I still couldn't figure out what is the tricky difference between the two app.

Comment: In my code, I never flip the order of the vertices, and you're never calling `diagIndices.position(0);` Other than that, I would try to move the vertices from the very edge of the screen to somewhere in the middle to make it easier to notice if it's rendering or not. Try to mirror the example as closely as possible, and it would be nice to see an updated version of your code now.